# How to use roaming settings between Windows 10 and XBOX One UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, xbox-one

I have a Windows 10 UWP app that uses roaming settings to store user settings. If a user installs the app on another Windows 10 machine, her settings will follow her there. Great!

I want to publish the app to Xbox One, but seems roaming settings are not supported: [UWP features not yet supported on Xbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/extension-sdks/uwp-limitations-on-xbox)

> Roaming settings are not synchronized on Xbox. The roaming setting APIs may be called, but settings will not be synchronized between devices.

How can I achieve this on Xbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document clearly states that RoamingSettings is not support synchronized, so there is currently no other way to call it.

You can explicitly remind users that the synchronization of roaming settings between Windows 10 devices and Xbox is not supported.

If you want to synchronize user settings, you can consider building your own server, save the user settings in the server (such as create a database to save the data), and synchronize them when the application is started.

Comment: Is there no easy way to save Xbox UWP app settings into MS cloud? Building my own server is too time consuming and expensive.

Comment: Hello, for UWP, the simple way is to use roaming settings for synchronization, but as the document says, roaming settings have not reached the same level of support on Xbox as the desktop, so if you need to synchronize settings across platforms, the recommended way is use self-built services to synchronize data

Comment: What about Xbox live? That can save to cloud from Xbox UWP? https://help.yoyogames.com/hc/en-us/articles/360031122031-UWP-Saving-And-Loading-When-Targeting-Xbox Could this be used to share settings between xbox and win10 uwp app?

Comment: Hello, Xbox Live is a service for Xbox, it can be used to save game data, but it does not mean that it can be used for UWP applications (not UWP games) to share settings between desktop and Xbox.

Answer (score 1):

Roaming settings will be [deprecated in Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingfolder).

One option could be to synchronize your settings via OneDrive instead. Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62600327/alternative-ways-of-roaming-of-app-settings-in-uwp/68503357#68503357).